# Vim shows ^M symbols and they aren't disappearing

Tags: windows, vim

I use Vim 7.3 under Windows 7 and have experienced a problem. Symbols `^M` are not disappearing despite any my efforts, `:e ++ff=dos` does not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

^M usually appear when the file is inconsistent with regards to the line terminators used. Try the following:

- Create `testfile` using vim with a few random lines, and write it in dos mode.
- Then run (hope you have cygwin installed):

  ```
   sed '2s/.$//' testfile > corruptfile
  ```

  This will remove the last character of the second line, creating an inconsistency in the line terminators used.
- Open `corruptfile` with vim. ^M symbols will appear so that you are made aware of the inconsistency.

In real life, programs that have been written with a single type of line-terminator in mind may produce such inconsistencies. While these inconsistencies seem innocent, they may cause you problems with other programs. E.g. [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) does not allow file with inconsistent line terminators to be added to a repository. Other programs may just fail silently.

To make ^M dissapear just make a global replacement:

```
:% s/^M//g
```

The `^M` is produced by pressing: `Ctrl+v <Enter>`

Then write back the file in the desired format:

```
:set ff=dos
:w
```

Comment: I know this trick and it does work. But why these ^M symbols happen in files created on Windows (not in Vim) while accessing from Windows? I met this many time and do not understand the logick.

Comment: The problem exists for file completion in **command line**, not in editor filed. For example, when I write `e: filenam<tab>` and awaiting that Vim completes typed  `filenam`, then Vim doesn't complete.

Comment: I added an explanation for ^M appearing. Could you elaborate more on which command line you mean? Is it windows shell (cmd)? Bash shell under cygwin? Something else?

Comment: It is windows shell (cmd). I have not cygwin (mingw instead).  
And regarding ^M: files were created in Code::Blocks and then I tried to edit them in Vim. I suggested that ^M are appeared due to presense of a several non-`CRLF`-lines. But did not found such lines.

Comment: If part 1 regards windows shell I strongly recommend splitting this question in two separate questions. Have you checked e.g. with `hexdump -c` that all lines in your file use the same line terminator? A oneliner for this would be `sed -e 's/[[:print:]]*//g' file | hexdump -c`. With a consistent file, the same pattern of line terminators characters will be repeated on the output. (sorry for the unix-slang :-) )

Comment: Yes, seems, you're right: it will be better to split this discussion on two separate.

Comment: I removed the first question, hope that's fine @OlegG

Comment: Also, edited out the answer to first question.

Answer (score 1):

The character that vim displays as ^M is `CR` (carriage return, ASCII character 13). Windows uses both `CR` and `LF` (new line, ASCII character 10) to encode line breaks in text files. Linux/Unix use only `LF` to encode line breaks, and Mac OS uses only `CR`.

If you open a text file created on a Windows computer on a Linux box, you may see trailing `CR` characters in each line. There are several ways to remove them. One is to replace them in vim as m000 suggested, another would be to `recode` the file:

```
recode ibmpc..latin1 SOME.TXT
```

Comment: If you'll read my question more accureate then you will see that I use Vim under Windows to edit files created under Windows also.

Comment: It can happen on Windows as well if at least one line uses only `LF` without `CR`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/799433/1630171) to a similar question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "If you open a text file created on a Windows computer on a Linux box, you'll see trailing...": This is only true for b-class editors who can't handle non-native line terminators properly. Definitely not true for vim.

Comment: @m000 I changed that to "may see". And even vim *will* display `CR` when at least one line uses only `LF`, see my other comment above.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I.e. vim will display line terminators when they are not consistent through the file :-)

Comment: Note that it's the classic Mac OS from the 80s and 90s that uses `CR`. Modern day macOS uses `LF` like other Unix-related OSs.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `:%s/\r//g` it just removes `^M`

Here is the asciinema tutorial
https://asciinema.org/a/HcwgOhLo40EPpPCk3PuhVOxjK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).